# Can't move a file in objective c

Tags: objective-c, console

I'm a beginner in this language.
I want to move a file from one folder to another my code is here.
The console give me  file exists at path twice
And the moveItemAtPath gives me always false

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
@autoreleasepool {

    NSString * originPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Downloads/1.wav"];
    NSString * finalPath  = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Desktop"];

    NSFileManager * manager = [[NSFileManager alloc]init];


    if( [ manager fileExistsAtPath:originPath]){
        NSLog(@"The file exists at: %@",originPath);
    }

    if( [manager fileExistsAtPath:finalPath]){
        NSLog(@"The file exists at: %@",finalPath);
    }

    if([manager moveItemAtPath:originPath toPath:finalPath error:nil]){
        NSLog(@"True"); 
    }else{
        NSLog(@"FALSE");
    }
}
return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should use `[NSFileManager defaultManager]`  instead of creating a new NSFileManager. It will return a singleton-instance of NSFileManager.
Add this to your second "ifFileExists"-check:

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:finalPath error:nil];
```

This will remove the item at the target-path, before moving a new one to this destination.

Comment: but doing this in theory it'll remove the folder desktop?? I am not understanding you well  I want to move the file from downloads to desktop

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, your final-path has to contain the file-name, not only /Desktop but /Desktop/1.wav